# Sorting Three vectors based on the arrangement of one, with duplicates.

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector

```
vector<int> reference = ages;
sort(ages.begin(),ages.end());
for (int i=0; i<20 ;++i){
    for (int j=0; j<20; ++j){
        if (ages[i]==reference[j]){
            cout << setw(LongestString(names))<<names[j] <<setw(agewidth)<<ages[i]<<setw(probwidth)<<prob[j]<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

So I have a three vectors and I want to sort them based off of the ages, and then reorder them. However, there are repetitions in the ages, so whenever it gets to those it prints them multiple times. Is there a way to prevent that without the creation of a structure?

Answer (score 0):

Generate a vector of indices from 0 to ages.size()-1. Sort the indices according to ages, probably using a lambda compare function. Then reorder all three vectors according to the sorted vector of indices. This will keep all three vectors in "sync", regardless of any duplicates in ages.

The reordering is simple if you just copy a vector according to indices sorted[i] = original[sorted_index[i]]. Reordering in place can also be done, as shown in the example below, but it's a little known algorithm, and if this is homework, I don't know where a student would be expected to be aware of this algorithm or be able to find examples of this algorithm. The algorithm is based on the fact that a permutation can be considered as a sequence of cycles:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation

```
    std::vector <int> A;                // ages
    std::vector <std::string> N;        // names
    std::vector <int> Z;                // zip codes
    std::vector <size_t> I;             // indices

    // vectors A, N, Z are initialized here ...

    // initialize vector of indices
    for(size_t i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
        I.push_back(i);
    // sort vector of indices according to A
    std::stable_sort(I.begin(), I.end(),
        [&A](size_t i, size_t j) {return 
        A[i] < A[j];});
    // reorder A, N, Z in place also restore I back to 0 to size-1
    // time complexity is O(n)
    // every move places an element in its sorted position
    for(size_t i = 0; i < A.size(); i++){
        size_t j, k;
        int tA;                         // temp variables
        std::string tN;
        int tZ;
        if(i != I[i]){
            tA = A[i];
            tN = N[i];
            tZ = Z[i];
            k = i;
            while(i != (j = I[k])){
                A[k] = A[j];
                N[k] = N[j];
                Z[k] = Z[j];
                I[k] = k;
                k = j;
            }
            A[k] = tA;
            N[k] = tN;
            Z[k] = tZ;
            I[k] = k;
        }
    }
```

Comment: But how would I prevent repitition of values given there are several values in vector names that correspond to the same ages?

Comment: @HowDoesOneR - it won't matter if the sort is stable (like std::stable_sort), then the original ordering of ages will be preserved. Even if the sort is not stable, it will still keep the three vectors in sync during the reordering. Duplicates of ages would not result in duplicate values in the other vectors (unless there are separate sets of duplicates in the other vectors).

Comment: When I try to use this code with SIZE=20 i get a segmentation fault? Am I using size incorrectly?

Comment: @HowDoesOneR - I[] needs to contain values 0 to SIZE-1 (the order doesn't matter). If you're stuck I can post a more complete example.

Comment: @HowDoesOneR - I updated my answer. Is this homework? If so, I'm not sure how students are supposed to be able to find algorithms like reorder in place, or "reorder according to".